# using dajax, dajaxice in heroku

Tags: django, dajaxice, dajax

I'm using dajax / dajaxice.

But when I upload my app to heroku, I found crash log

```
2012-12-04T08:32:36+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:45991 --noreload`

2012-12-04T08:32:37+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: No module named dajax

2012-12-04T08:32:39+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
```

No module dajax in heroku server.

How Can i Fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you put

```
django-dajax==0.9.2
django-dajaxice==0.5.4
```

in the [requirements.txt](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-pip)